# Microsoft CRM 2011 Impersonation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I want to know in CRM 2011, if I initiated the organization service with user (A) and then I impersonated with user (B).

Which user permissions will be used by CRM when I try to execute a request (i.e create account, ...)?

**For example:**

I have

- User (A) who don't have permissions to act on behalf another user.
- User (B) who have system administrator permissions and act on behalf another user permission.

I create the organization service based on Windows Authentication and log-in with user (A) as following:

```
Uri organizationUri = new Uri("http://localhost:5555/RMS/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
Uri homeRealmUri = null;
ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();       
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
OrganizationServiceProxy orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null);
```

Then I impersonate like that

```
orgProxy.CallerId = userBGuid;
```

When I am trying to execute WhoAmIRequest; I get the following error:

**System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: User does not have the privilege to act on behalf another user. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).**

When I give User (A) permissions to act on behalf of another user, this code pass successfully.

Comment: Your question answers itself..you said it yourself, when you impersonate the user then it tries to act as userA who doesnt have permissions and thats why you get the error but when you give him permissions, then you pass it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it's expected behavior. If you set `CallerId = userBGuid` it means that even when you are logged as userA, all activities done on behalf of userB. UserA should have priviliges to do this.